# Infinite loop in haskell

Tags: haskell, infinite-loop, lazy-evaluation, infinite

So I am writing a program to generate a list of prime numbers in haskell. I create two functions shown below:

```
{-
Given a list of prime numbers, this function will
add the next prime number to the list. So, given the 
list [2, 3], it will return [2, 3, 5]
-}
nextPrime xs =  xs ++ [lastVal + nextCounts]
    where
        lastVal       =  (head . reverse) $ xs
        isNextPrime y =  0 `elem` ( map ( y `mod`) xs )
        nextVals      =  (map isNextPrime [lastVal, lastVal+1 ..] )
        nextCounts    =  length $ takeWhile (\x -> x) nextVals


allPrimes xs = allPrimes np
    where 
        np = nextPrime xs
```

Now the function 'nextPrime' is doing what it is supposed to do. However, when I do a call to allPrimes as shown below:

```
take 5 $ allPrimes [2,3]
```

The program goes into an infinite loop. I thought Haskells "lazy" features were supposed to take care of all this? What am I missing??

Comment: Question: When does allPrimes produces the first value? Ans: Never. It just calls it self with a larger list and this step never ends. A trivial solution is to produce some result before recursing again.

Comment: I would suggest instead of writing a function that takes a list and then returns a new list with the next prime, why not just make a function that produces an infinite list of primes?  Haskell uses lazy evaluation, so you only compute an element of the list when you ask for it.

Answer (score 3):

If you start evaluating the expression on paper you can see why laziness doesn't help here. Start with your expression:

```
take 5 $ allPrimes [2,3]
```

First, attempt to evaluate the allPrimes expression:

```
allPrimes [2, 3]
```

which becomes

```
allPrimes np
    where 
        np = nextPrime [2, 3]
```

put the things from the `where` clause into the expression and it becomes

```
allPrimes (nextPrime [2, 3])
```

Now, evaluate `nextPrime [2, 3]` (you can do this in `ghci` since that function works) and get `[2, 3, 5]`, which you can replace in the previous expression, and it becomes

```
allPrimes [2, 3, 5]
```

repeat the above and it becomes

```
allPrimes [2, 3, 5, 7]
```

and there is your problem! `allPrimes` never evaluated to any values, it evaluates to `allPrimes` applied to longer and longer lists. To see where laziness does work, try evaluating on paper a function like `zip` from the `Prelude`:

```
zip :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a,b)]
zip (a:as) (b:bs) = (a,b) : zip as bs

zip [1, 2, 3] ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

`a` becomes `1`, `as` becomes `[2, 3]`, `b` becomes `'a'`, `bs` becomes `['b', 'c']` so you get

```
(1, 'a') : zip [2, 3] ['b', 'c']
```

The difference here is that there is a list with a **value**, then the rest of the list is an **expression**. In your `allPrimes` function, you just keep getting more **expressions**.

For more information, look into **Weak Head Normal Form** however if you are new to Haskell I recommend you get comfortable with the syntax and with the basics of "Thinking in Haskell" before you start looking at things like WHNF.

Comment: That `[(1, 'a'), zip ...` thing is actually ill-typed, since `zip` returns a list of tuples.

Comment: True. I'll Remove it.

Comment: @Drew: nothing forces the call to `nextPrime [2, 3]`, so wouldn't it be `allPrimes (nextPrime (nextPrime ... [2, 3])...)`?

Comment: I don't think so, but I don't know enough about graph reduction to say for sure.

Answer (score 1):

I'd read Drew's answer for a good explanation of what's going wrong, but for a quick demonstration for how to make this work,

```
nextPrime xs =  xs ++ [lastVal + nextCounts]
  where
    lastVal       =  (head . reverse) $ xs
    isNextPrime y =  0 `elem` ( map ( y `mod`) xs )
    -- ^ Style note, this name is super misleading, since it returns
    -- false when the number is prime :)
    nextVals      =  (map isNextPrime [lastVal, lastVal+1 ..] )
    nextCounts    =  length $ takeWhile (\x -> x) nextVals


allPrimes xs = last np : allPrimes np
  where np = nextPrime xs
```

Now we're constructing the list as we go, and haskell is lazy so it can grab the last element of `np` before evaluating the `allPrimes np`. In other words `head (a : infiniteLoop)` is `a`, not an infinite loop.

However this is **really** innefficient. Lists are singly linked in Haskell so `last` is `O(n)` as opposed to `O(1)` in something like Python. And `++` is also costly, `O(n)` for the length of the first list.

Instead

```
 nextPrime xs = lastVal + nextCounts
   where lastVal     = head xs
         isNextPrime = 0 `elem` map (y `rem`) xs
         nextVals    = map isNextPrime [lastVal ..]
         nextCount   = length $ takeWhile id nextVals

 allPrimes xs = p : allPrimes (p:xs)
    where p = nextPrime xs
```

So we keep the list reversed to avoid those costly traversals. We can also simplify `nextPrime`

```
import Data.Maybe
nextPrime xs = fromJust nextPrime
  where isPrime y =  not $ 0 `elem` map (rem y) xs
        nextPrime = find isPrime [head xs ..]
```

Where we just search the list for the first element which is prime and add it to our list. The `fromJust` is normally bad, if there were no next primes we'd get an error. But since we know mathematically that there will always be a next prime, this is safe.

In the end, the code looks like

```
 import Data.Maybe
 import Data.List
 nextPrime xs = fromJust nextPrime
   where isPrime y = 0 `notElem` map (rem y) xs
         nextPrime = find isPrime [head xs ..]
 allPrimes xs = p : allPrimes (p:xs)
   where p = nextPrime xs
```

To evaluate it, call `allPrimes [2]`.

---

An even cleaner way to do this would be to have a function `isPrime` that returns whether a number is prime or not. And then just to have

```
allPrimes = filter isPrime [1..]
```

But I'll leave that to the curious reader.

Comment: While your suggestion is cleaner, it would probably be slower. An `isPrime a` function can be implemented more efficiently if it has a list of all the primes before `a`.

Comment: @Drew This is true, that's why is said cleaner not faster :)

Comment: Fair enough. Personally I hesitate to recommend a cleaner but slower solution, that seems like the wrong tradeoff to me.

Comment: @Drew I mentioned it because `filter` is a very common idiom and usually worth bringing up in any post on list processing. But the more efficient implementation is 10 lines above it so I think it's ok here

Answer (score 0):

As Drew pointed out, your function `allPrimes` doesn't profit from lazyness since we never have acess to what it calculates. This is because the list we want to peek into is an argument of allPrimes, not a return value.

So we need to expose the list allPrimes is building, and still keep a function call that will infinitely build the following value of this list.

Well, since allPrimes is the re-application of itself over and over, we just need a function that exposes the intermediate values. And we have one!

```
 iterate f a == [a, f (f a),...]
```

So with iterate and nextPrime, we could build the following (rather strange) functions:

```
-- nextPrime renamed as nextPrimeList
infiniteListofListofPrimes =  iterate nextPrimeList [2,3]
primeN n =   (infiniteListofListofPrimes !! n) !! n
takeN n  =  take n (infiniteListofListofPrimes !! n)
```

We are generating our primes, but it's not looking great. We would rather have  `[primes]`, not  redundant `[[some primes]]`.

The next step is building the list on WHNF:

```
elem1:elem2:aux
where aux = newvalue:aux
```

Where `aux` will calculate the newvalue and leave everything in place for the next one.

For that we need `nextPrime` sticking to generating one new prime:

```
nextPrime xs = lastVal + nextCounts
```

And finding the `aux` that can build `listOfPrimes` forever.

I came up with this:

```
  infiniteListofPrimes = 2:3:aux 2
       where aux n  = nextPrime (take n infiniteListofPrimes):(aux (n+1))
```